# How can "[blank] of [blank]" be condensed into one word?

Tags: single-word-requests, compounds

Maybe I am not asking this the right way.

For example, could "**illusion of pain**" be condensed into one word or by simply using fewer words?

This is not to be "pain-illusion." That is too different. (Also, what is this one's name?)

Lastly, even though there is only one example, the best answer is a general formula or just the grammar rule(s).

Comment: Are you asking for a single word that means *"illusion of pain",* or for a general formula which will take a phrase like *"end of time"* or *"fear of horses*" and turn it into a single word? If you're asking for the general formula, there's no such thing. (How could such a formula produce *armageddon* and *equinophobia*?)

Comment: This looks like a form of inversion, but I dont know if it has a more specific name. But it's unclear what you are asking.

Comment: From a grammatical angle of the words, I think you're looking at possessive case.

Comment: +1 But suggesting migration to ell.se

Comment: These phrases are confusing:"That is too different. (Also, what is this one's name?)" and  "...the best answer is a general formula or just the grammar rule(s)". Were you asking a question in the last phrase? If you wish your question to be reopened, please clarify.

Comment: I am satisfied with the one answer. If you want to change the question-wording, go for it.

Answer (score 2):

There can be no single rule for  of . It is simply too vast a qualification and there is no one size that fits all.

The only one rule that can apply is,
*box of wood*, which may be written as *wood-box* or *wooden-box* but Lawrence of Arabia cannot be Arabia-Lawrence, Arabia's Lawrence or Arabian Lawrence maybe more appropriate. *Illusion of pain* may have to be treated completely differently from the above two and would have to be reworded as ***imagined pain***.

Hence, we can say when it refers to the material something is made of, like a box (made) of wood, a shoe (cast out) of iron; it can be written as *wood-box* or *iron-shoe*.

When *of* denotes a quality, association or possession to a place or clan or a person.

> *Prince of Persia
>
>   Property of the Clintons
>
>   Beauty of Helen*

The possessive state may work:

> *Persia's Prince
>
>   Clintons' property
>
>   Helen's beauty.*

In Case I and II, a lot of the time, the adjective form can be used : *Wooden Box*, *Persian Prince*.

However one case does not fit all, and there are as many exceptions as the words that fit into the rule.